# Crack in moulding

Tags: woodworking

I just had new cabinets installed. I was inspecting crown moulding and found a crack where it was nailed. I showed contractor the crack. He filled it. Should I expect a new piece of moulding. Or is the filling of a crack acceptable?

Comment: Is this painted or stained? I know you can see the crack when you look for it, but would an impartial individual stand in your kitchen and see the filled crack at a glance? Generally, cracks and nail holes get filled, but sometimes it's a matter of degrees.

Comment: If the crack is purely aesthetic and minimal, then filling it is normal.  If the crack split the moulding for a significant length, is causing other issues and/or is obviously visible after remediation (filling, sanding, finishing, etc) you have a case for replacement.

Answer (score 1):

filling a crack is SOP. it might need to be touched up so finishes match, but its entirely acceptable

Comment: I agree filling a crack is SOP but it should match.